# how to continue remaining part of execution even after the nested if condition failed

Tags: python

I am just trying to verify a tic tac toe board whose values I have in a list of list.

```
board = ([1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 2])


def print_winner(variable):
    if variable == 1:
        return print("Winner of this board is Player1")
    else:
        return print("Winner of this board is Player2")


def interpret(game_board):
    if game_board[0][0] != 0:
        if game_board[0][1] and game_board[0][2] == game_board[0][0]:
            print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
        elif game_board[1][0] and game_board[2][0] == game_board[0][0]:
            print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
        elif game_board[1][1] and game_board[2][2] == game_board[0][0]:
            print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
    elif game_board[0][1] != 0:
        if game_board[1][1] and game_board[2][1] == game_board[0][1]:
            print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
    elif game_board[0][2] != 0:
        if game_board[1][2] and game_board[2][2] == game_board[0][2]:
            print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
        elif game_board[1][2] and game_board[2][0]:
            print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
    elif game_board[1][0] != 0:
        if game_board[1][1] and game_board[1][2] == game_board[1][0]:
            print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
    elif game_board[2][0] != 0:
        if game_board[2][1] and game_board[2][2] == game_board[2][0]:
            print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
    else:
        print("No Winner")


interpret(board)
```

what is the issue with above code is I don't know how to instruct my program to continue with the remaining piece of code once all my first nested if statements failed. Because of which my code is not giving any output. 
Expected output is `"No winner"`.

Comment: Use try-except statement for each case: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: What do you mean by "remaining piece of code"?

Comment: In my code first if will be true but none of the nested if are true so i will not get any output on the screen. So is there any way I can instruct my nested if to continue with the elif part of the main if. Because I want output has "No Winner". @MSeifert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are using `and` incorrectly. You need to specify the conditions on either operand of `and`. For example:

```
if game_board[0][1] == game_board[0][0] and game_board[0][2] == game_board[0][0]
```

OR

```
if game_board[0][1] == game_board[0][2] == game_board[0][0]
```

instead of:

```
if game_board[0][1] and game_board[0][2] == game_board[0][0]
```

However you could also use a `set` and check if it only contains one number:

```
if len({game_board[0][0], game_board[0][1], game_board[0][2]}) == 1:
```

The actual question about

> how to instruct my program to continue with the remaining piece of code once all my first nested if statements failed

is actually quite easy. Use normal `if`s and `return` if one condition matched.

Together with some other improvements (you always printed the `game_board[0][0]`) it would look like this:

```
def interpret(game_board):
    if game_board[0][0] != 0:
        if len({game_board[0][0], game_board[0][1], game_board[0][2]}) == 1:
            return print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
        elif len({game_board[0][0], game_board[1][0], game_board[2][0]}) == 1:
            return print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
        elif len({game_board[0][0], game_board[1][1], game_board[2][2]}) == 1:
            return print(print_winner(game_board[0][0]))
    if game_board[0][1] != 0:
        if len({game_board[0][1], game_board[1][1], game_board[2][1]}) == 1:
            return print(print_winner(game_board[0][1]))
    if game_board[0][2] != 0:
        if len({game_board[0][2], game_board[1][2], game_board[2][2]}) == 1:
            return print(print_winner(game_board[0][2]))
        elif len({game_board[0][2], game_board[1][1], game_board[2][0]}) == 1:
            return print(print_winner(game_board[0][2]))
    if game_board[1][0] != 0:
        if len({game_board[1][0], game_board[1][1], game_board[1][2]}) == 1:
            return print(print_winner(game_board[1][0]))
    if game_board[2][0] != 0:
        if len({game_board[2][0], game_board[2][1], game_board[2][2]}) == 1:
            return print(print_winner(game_board[2][0]))
    return print("No Winner")
```

This works because `print` returns `None` and prints to the `stdout`.

Comment: Thank you very much this works as expected and thanks for pointing out another mistake as well.@MSeifert